# Lazarus: TForm1 Prints the size of a "Thumbnail image" - not size of TForm1

Tags: canvas, printing, thumbnails, lazarus

Removed the original description of the problem -

"***printer output to paper is Thumbnail size***" - problem solved.

***Cause for the problem:***

*"Printer's resolution is higher than your screen's, e.g. for 96ppi vs 600ppi, you'll have about 1/6th of your image size"* - post on StackOverFlow.

Original code:

```
    procedure TForm1.PrintClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    if PrintDialog1.Execute then
    begin
    with Printer do
        begin
            BeginDoc;
            Panel1.PaintTo(Canvas, 0,0); //prints contents of Panel1 only
            Form1.PaintTo(Canvas, 0, 600); //screenshot/cast of Window
            EndDoc;
        end;
    end;
    end;
```

---

SOLVED CODE:

Need to copy the content to the Clipboard and print from the Clipboard:

```
    procedure TForm1.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
        MyRect: TRect;
        scale: Double;
        R: TRect;
        Bitmap: TBitmap;
    begin
        if PrintDialog1.Execute then
        begin
            Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
            try
            //copy content of Panel1 to Clipboard:
            R := Rect(0, 0, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height);
            Bitmap.SetSize(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height);
            Bitmap.Canvas.CopyRect(R, Panel1.Canvas, R);

            //print content of Clipboard:
            Printer.BeginDoc;

            {scale := Printer.PageWidth / Bitmap.Width;         //large print
            scale := (Printer.PageWidth / (Bitmap.Width / 2));  //twice the size of large print
            scale := ((Printer.PageWidth/2) / Bitmap.Width);    //reduce size}
            scale := Printer.PageWidth / Bitmap.Width;          //print full page

            ShowMessage(FloatToStr(scale)); // '30', '17.5', '8.75'
            { horizontal pixels, vertical pixels, bit depth 600 x 600 x 24}
            MyRect.Left := 0;
            MyRect.Top := 0;
            MyRect.Right := trunc(Bitmap.Width * scale);
            MyRect.Bottom := trunc(Bitmap.Height * scale);
            Printer.Canvas.StretchDraw(MyRect, Bitmap);
            Printer.EndDoc;
            finally
            bitmap.free;
            end;
        end;
    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

Needed to copy the content to the clipboard and print from there - code now enlarge and print more or less the size I wanted :D
** code 'Frankensteined' from all over the web